# Validando select com jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou criando um formulário para inscrição onde o mesmo existe alguns selects, como escolha de curso e data de nascimento, gostaria de saber como faço para tornar obrigatório o usuário selecionar alguma coisa usando esta biblioteca [jquery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```html
<select name="cursos_categoria" id="cursos_categoria">
  <option>Selecione a categoria de cursos</option>
  <option value="Imersão">Imersão</option>
  <option value="Aperfeiçoamento">Aperfeiçoamento</option>
  <option value="Especialização">Especialização</option>
  <option value="Superior">Superior</option>
  <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sérgio, para utilizar o jquery.validate é bem simples, você precisa apenas incluir a classe required no seu elemento e no js chamar o plugin passando o seletor que é o seu formulário.

**Exemplo:**

```
<form id="registerForm">
  <select name="cursos_categoria" id="cursos_categoria" class='required'>
    <option value="">Selecione a categoria de cursos</option>
    <option value="Imersão">Imersão</option>
    <option value="Aperfeiçoamento">Aperfeiçoamento</option>
    <option value="Especialização">Especialização</option>
    <option value="Superior">Superior</option>
    <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

E depois:

```
 $("#registerForm").validate();
```

Repare no seguinte, a sua primeira option esta sendo entendida como uma option valida, para você fazer o plugin entender que esta option é apenas informativa coloque o atributo value e deixe sem nenhum valor.

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/5RrGa/1664/)

Comment: Que simples! tinha feito vários testes usando alguns exemplos que vi e nenhum tinha dado certo, muito obrigado Gabriel

Comment: @SérgioMachado que bom que tudo deu certo :)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o seguinte código

Referencia Bootstrap 4
Segue seu formulário:

```
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="txtDataInicio">Data Início:</label>
                        <select name="cursos_categoria" id="cursos_categoria">
                            <option>Selecione a categoria de cursos</option>
                            <option value="Imersão">Imersão</option>
                            <option value="Aperfeiçoamento">Aperfeiçoamento</option>
                            <option value="Especialização">Especialização</option>
                            <option value="Superior">Superior</option>
                            <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Usando o framework jquary.Validate, crie o seguinte script JS:

```
$(function () {
   $.validator.addMethod(
       "Curso",
       function (value, element) {
           if ($("#cursos_categoria").val() === "") {
               return false;
           } else {
               return true;
           }
       }
   );

   $("#idFormulario").validate({
            onfocusout: function (e) {
                this.element(e);
            },
            onkeyup: false,
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest(".form-control").addClass("is-invalid");
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest(".form-control").removeClass("is-invalid");
                $(element).closest(".form-control").addClass("is-valid");
            },
            errorElement: "div",
            errorClass: "invalid-feedback",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent(".input-group-prepend").length) {
                    $(element).siblings(".invalid-feedback").append(error);
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            rules: {
                'Curso': {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                'Curso': {
                    required: "Selecione o Curso!"
                }
            }

        });

});
```

Segue link de referencia: https://coderanch.com/t/554835/languages/jQuery-Validator-select

Para que tudo isso funcione você precisa ter as referencias do Jquary Validate
pode consultar no seguinte link [JQueryValidate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 0):

utilize o seguinte codigo:

https://jsfiddle.net/7xhgjtag/

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
  <select name="listaopt" id="OptList">
    <option value="selecione...">selecione</option>
    <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option 2">option 2</option>
    <option value="option 3">option 3</option>
    <option value="option 4">option 4</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#myform').validate({
  rules: {
    listaopt: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

você encontra isso na documentação: http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method